# Android consulta ws no autorizada. OAuth 2.0

Tags: android, curl, oauth2

Buenos dias.
Tengo que realizar una consulta a un WS para que me retorne un access_token, este WS tiene seguridad OAuth 2.0, necesito pasarle un client_id y client_secret, caso contrario me devuelve 'no autorizado'.
Este es el cURL:

```
curl -X POST -vu <client_id>:<client_secret> http://<ip_ws>:8080/oauth/token -H "Accept: application/json" -d "password=<password>&username=<user>&grant_type=password&scope=read%20write&client_secret=<client_secret>&client_id=<client_id>"
```

Desde consola de Windows puedo realizar la consulta, pero no puedo realizar esto desde mi app de Android, ni PostMan.
Nose como configurarlo para autentificarme ante OAuth 2.0

Es posible realizar una peticion con el formato cURL? o hay que acudir a HttpURLConnection la cual no eh sabido utilizar para estos casos.
Porfavor responsan con la mayor cantidad de informacion posible, librerias y mas.
Saludos!